# Receive null in BroadcastReceiver from API 25

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

I send object ( implemented Serializable ) through to intent with AlarmMananger

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    Event event = new Event();

    event.setTitle("title");

    b.putSerializable(KEY_EVENT, event);

    intent.putExtras(b);

    int id = 0;

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  id, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, interval, pendingIntent);
```

and in BroadcastReceiver i receive intent and try to receive my custom object:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("TAG", "onReceive: ");

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

   Event event = (Event) intent.getExtras().getSerializable(KEY_EVENT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String title = "";

    if (event != null) {

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(event.getTitle())) {
            title = event.getTitle();
        }

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "event = null");
    }


}
```

There are different behavior between APIs, on API 19 Event object is NOT null and on API 25 Event object is null. I tried to send primitive types, and it's ok, but something wrong with custom object. Who can help?

Comment: While [this blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html) focuses on `Parcelable`, the same basic problem will be seen with `Serializable`.

Comment: My object implements Serializable, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: Convert the `Parcelable`/`Serializable` into a `byte[]` and put that in the extra. Then convert it back when you receive the `Intent`.